# c++ program doesn't continue on after loop

Tags: c++, function, class, visual-studio-2019, do-while

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class movie {
private:

string rating;

public:
string title;
string director;


movie(string aTitle, string aDirector, string aRatings) {
    title = aTitle;
    director = aDirector;
    setrating(aRatings);
};

void setrating(string aRating) {

    // this loop checks to see if the rating entered is valid
 do
    if (aRating == "G" || aRating == "PG" || aRating == "PG-13" || aRating == "18" || aRating == "NR") {


        rating = aRating;
    }
    else {

        cout << "rating must be, G, PG, PG-13, 18 or NR \n";
        cout << "enter the rating: ";
        cin >> aRating;
    }
 while (aRating != "G" || aRating != "PG" || aRating != "PG-13" || aRating != "18" || aRating != "NR");
}

string getrating() {

    return rating;

}
};

int main()
{

movie avengers("The Avengers", "Joss Whedon", "PG-13");
avengers.setrating("dog");

cout << avengers.title << "\n";
cout << avengers.director << "\n";
cout << avengers.getrating() << "\n";
}
```

i cant seem to get the program out of the while loop, once i enter the correct value the loop stops but the rest of the program does not continue. If the correct value is already there the program just displays nothing.

the program is supposed to ask the user to enter the correct rating if the rating entered is incorrect the program will loop till the variable = one of the values. then the program then should display the title, director and rating(this last part is not currently working).

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I recommend passing large structures, anything larger than the processor's register, by reference, or if you are not changing the parameter, pass by `const` reference.  This prevents the compiler from making a copy of the object; which will also make your code more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logical condition is not correct:

```
while (aRating != "G" || aRating != "PG" || aRating != "PG-13" || aRating != "18" || aRating != "NR");
```

Write out some examples, and you'll see that this condition is always true. (any value of `aRating` will always be either *not G* or *not PG*, for example).

You need to replace all the `||`s with `&&`s.

Also, your `do-while` loop is flawed, since you won't be assigning to `rating` when you need to. Instead, you could restructure it like this:

```
do 
{
   cout << "rating must be, G, PG, PG-13, 18 or NR \n";
   cout << "enter the rating: ";
   cin >> aRating;
} while (aRating != "G" && aRating != "PG" && aRating != "PG-13" && aRating != "18" && aRating != "NR");

// now just assign
rating = aRating;
```

This also avoids having to essentially spell out the constraints twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||` in the line

```
while (aRating != "G" || aRating != "PG" || aRating != "PG-13" || aRating != "18" || aRating != "NR");
```

A better alternateive would be put the logic of "is rating valid" in its own function and use it in both the `if` statement and the `do while` statement.

```
bool isValidRating(strting const& aRating)
{
   return (aRating == "G" || aRating == "PG" || aRating == "PG-13" || aRating == "18" || aRating == "NR");
}

void setrating(string aRating)
{
   // this loop checks to see if the rating entered is valid
   do
   {
      if ( isValidRating(aRating) )
      {

         rating = aRating;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "rating must be, G, PG, PG-13, 18 or NR \n";
         cout << "enter the rating: ";
         cin >> aRating;
      }

   } while ( !isValidRating(aRating) );
}
```

The second function can be simplied to:

```
void setrating(string aRating)
{
   while  ( !isValidRating(aRating) )
   {
      cout << "rating must be, G, PG, PG-13, 18 or NR \n";
      cout << "enter the rating: ";
      cin >> aRating;
   }

   rating = aRating;
}
```